# Listas Doblemente Enlazadas y Perdidas de Memoria

Tags: c++

Necesito ayuda con mi código, realmente no estoy viendo cual es mi problema, el código es en C++
Tengo la clase Lista y su definición

```
class Lista {
public:

    /**
     * Constructor por defecto de la clase Lista.
     */
    Lista();

    /**
     * Constructor por copia de la clase Lista.
     */
    Lista(const Lista& l);

    /**
     * Destructor de la clase Lista.
     */
    ~Lista();

    /**
     * Operador asignacion
     * @param aCopiar
     * @return
     */
    Lista& operator=(const Lista& aCopiar);

    /**
     * Agrega un elemento al principio de la Lista.
     * @param elem elemento a agregar
     */
    void agregarAdelante(const int& elem);

    /**
     * Agrega un elemento al final de la Lista.
     * @param elem elemento a agregar
     */
    void agregarAtras(const int& elem);

    /**
     * Elimina el i-ésimo elemento de la Lista.
     * @param i posición del elemento a eliminar
     */
    void eliminar(Nat i);

    /**
     * Devuelve la cantidad de elementos que contiene la Lista.
     * @return
     */
    int longitud() const;

    /**
     * Devuelve el elemento en la i-ésima posición de la Lista.
     * @param i posición del elemento a devolver.
     * @return referencia no modificable
     */
    const int& iesimo(Nat i) const;
    /**
     * Devuelve el elemento en la i-ésima posición de la Lista.
     * @param i posición del elemento a devolver.
     * @return referencia modificable
     */
    int& iesimo(Nat i);

    /**
     * Muestra la lista en un ostream
     * formato de salida: [a_0, a_1, a_2, ...]
     * @param o
     */
    void mostrar(ostream& o);

    /**
     * Utiliza el método mostrar(os) para sobrecargar el operador <<
     */
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, Lista& l) {
        l.mostrar(os);
        return os;
    }

private:

    struct Nodo {//struct es una clase publica
        Nodo* anterior;
        Nodo* siguiente;
        int dato;
    }lista;

    int tam_;
    Nodo* prim;
    Nodo* fin;

};

y tengo problemas de Invalid Read cuando ejecuto 

void Lista::agregarAdelante(const int& elem) {
    Nodo* node = new Nodo(); //preguntar porque Nodo()
    node->dato = elem;

    if(prim == nullptr){
        node->siguiente = nullptr;
        node->anterior  = nullptr;
        prim = node;
        fin = prim;

    }

    else if(tam_ == 1){//Tamaño 1 
        node->siguiente = prim;
        node->anterior  = nullptr;
        prim->anterior  = node;
        prim = node;

    }

    else if(prim != nullptr){
        node->siguiente = this->prim; //el nuevo nodo apunta a la cabeza
        node->anterior = nullptr;
        this->prim->anterior = node;
        this->prim = node; //pongo la cabeza en su lugar
    }

    this->tam_++;           //aumento la longitud en 1

}

//Aclaro el constructor de Lista es.

Lista::Lista(): tam_(0), prim(nullptr), fin(nullptr), lista() {
}
```

Tengo 3 casos

Prim es el primer elemento de la Lista, y Fin el Último
Si hay un solo elemento Prim y Fin son iguales y apuntan al mismo nodo

La lista permite ir y volver entre cada elemento con siguiente y anterior

1. Prim y Fin apuntan a Nullptr y tam_ == 0
2. Prim y Fin apuntan a un Nodo con un elemento alojado y tam_ == 1
3. Caso génerico con mas de 1 elemento en la Lista,
   Que es lo que está mal de mi función AgregarAdelante?

Resto del código

```
Lista::Lista(const Lista& l) : Lista(){
    //Inicializa una lista vacía y luego utiliza operator= para no duplicar el código de la copia de una lista.
    *this = l;
}

Lista::~Lista() {
    Nodo* apuntar = prim;

    while(apuntar != nullptr){
        apuntar = apuntar->siguiente;

        //el anterior del siguiente apunta al anterior de este
        if(apuntar != nullptr){
            apuntar->anterior = prim->anterior;
        }
        delete(prim);

        //en el while no entran tam_ = 0, por que no entran prim y fin -> nullptr

        //cambia algo si le quito los parentesis?
        prim = apuntar;

    }

    this->tam_ = 0;
}
//Pre:{TRUE}
Lista& Lista::operator=(const Lista& aCopiar) {
    //Crear funcion privada para borrar la basura de this que queda huerfana, sin llamar al destructor
    Nodo* aBorrar = this->prim;
    while(aBorrar != nullptr){
        aBorrar = aBorrar->siguiente;
        if(prim->siguiente != nullptr){
            (prim->siguiente)->anterior = prim->anterior;
        }
        delete(prim);


        //cambia algo si le quito los parentesis?
        prim = aBorrar;

    }
    this->tam_ = 0;

    Nodo* recorrer = aCopiar.fin; //contexto Lista me permite usar variables internas como métodos

    while(recorrer != nullptr){//recorrer se anula al llegar al principio
        this->agregarAdelante(recorrer->dato);
        recorrer = recorrer->anterior;
    }

    return  *this;
}
//Post: {this =obs aCopiar y no hay alliasing entre this y aCopiar}

//revisar el parametro
void Lista::agregarAdelante(const int& elem) {
    Nodo* node = new Nodo(); //preguntar porque Nodo()
    node->dato = elem;

    if(prim == nullptr){
        node->siguiente = nullptr;
        node->anterior  = nullptr;
        prim = node;
        fin = prim;

    }

    else if(tam_ == 1){
        node->siguiente = prim;
        node->anterior  = nullptr;
        prim->anterior  = node;
        prim = node;

    }

    else if(prim != nullptr){
        node->siguiente = this->prim; //el nuevo nodo apunta a la cabeza
        node->anterior = nullptr;
        this->prim->anterior = node;
        this->prim = node; //pongo la cabeza en su lugar
    }

    this->tam_++;           //aumento la longitud en 1

}

void Lista::agregarAtras(const int& elem) {
    Nodo* node = new Nodo(); //preguntar porque Nodo()
    node->dato = elem;

    if(fin == nullptr){//prim-> nullptr  fin-> nullptr tam_ = 0
        node->siguiente = nullptr;
        node->anterior  = nullptr;
        fin  = node;
        prim = fin;


    }
    else if(tam_ == 1){// prim/fin->[e]<->node
        node->siguiente = nullptr;
        node->anterior  = prim;
        prim->siguiente = node;
        fin = node;
    }

    else if(fin != nullptr){
        node->siguiente = nullptr; //el nuevo nodo apunta al final
        node->anterior  = this->fin; //creo el anterior
        fin->siguiente = node;
        this->fin = node; //pongo el final en su lugar
    }

    this->tam_++;           //aumento la longitud en 1
}

void Lista::eliminar(Nat i) {
    Nodo* recorrer = new Nodo();
    recorrer = this->prim;
    while(i > 0){
        recorrer = recorrer->siguiente;
        i--;
    }
    if(recorrer->siguiente != nullptr && recorrer->anterior != nullptr){
        (recorrer->siguiente)->anterior = recorrer->anterior;
        (recorrer->anterior)->siguiente = recorrer->siguiente;
    }
    //Modifico Fin
    else if(recorrer->siguiente == nullptr && recorrer->anterior != nullptr){
        (recorrer->anterior)->siguiente = recorrer->siguiente;
        fin = recorrer->anterior;

    }
    //Modifico Prim
    else if(recorrer->siguiente != nullptr && recorrer->anterior == nullptr){
        (recorrer->siguiente)->anterior = recorrer->anterior;
        prim = recorrer->siguiente;
    }
    /*else if(recorrer->siguiente == nullptr && recorrer->anterior == nullptr){
    } No es necesario
*/

    delete recorrer;
    recorrer = nullptr;
    this->tam_--;
}

int Lista::longitud() const {
    return this->tam_;
}
//segmentation fault
const int& Lista::iesimo(Nat i) const {
    assert(i < tam_);
    Nodo* recorrer = new Nodo();
    recorrer = this->prim;
    int cont = 0;
    const int& data = recorrer->dato;


    while(cont != i){//recorrer esta adelantado del cont, necesito cortar antes de que cont sea i
        recorrer = recorrer->siguiente;
        cont++;
    }


    return data;//lo devuelve como referencia, tiene aliasing
}


int& Lista::iesimo(Nat i) {
    assert(i < tam_);
    Nodo* recorrer = new Nodo();
    recorrer = this->prim;
    int* data = nullptr;


    while(i > 0 ){//i = 0 es el ultimo nat, no puedo pasarme
        recorrer = recorrer->siguiente;
        i--;
    }
    data = &(recorrer->dato);


    return *data;
}

void Lista::mostrar(ostream& o) {
    Nodo* recorrer = new Nodo();
    recorrer = this->prim;

    while(recorrer != nullptr){
        if((recorrer->anterior) == nullptr){
            o << "Nullptr";
        }
        o << "<--->";
        o << "[ "<< recorrer->dato << " ]";
        o << "<--->";

        if((recorrer->siguiente) == nullptr){
            o <<"Nullptr";
        }
        recorrer = recorrer->siguiente;

    }

    delete recorrer;
    recorrer = nullptr;
}
```

SUMARIO DE VALGRIND:

```
==9137== Invalid read of size 8
==9137==    at 0x163B51: Lista::~Lista() (Lista.hpp:15)
==9137==    by 0x1666DC: lista_test_test_eliminar_elementos_Test::TestBody() (lista_tests.cpp:93)
==9137==    by 0x19C1D1: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x195304: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x171F13: testing::Test::Run() (gtest-all.cc:3973)
==9137==    by 0x1728C2: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4149)
==9137==    by 0x172F7D: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4267)
==9137==    by 0x17E37E: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest-all.cc:6633)
==9137==    by 0x19D66B: bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x1963C6: bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x17CD7F: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gtest-all.cc:6242)
==9137==    by 0x1AE220: RUN_ALL_TESTS() (gtest.h:22104)
==9137==  Address 0x4dd9af8 is 8 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==9137==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9137==    by 0x163FE2: Lista::eliminar(unsigned long) (Lista.hpp:148)
==9137==    by 0x1665F3: lista_test_test_eliminar_elementos_Test::TestBody() (lista_tests.cpp:91)
==9137==    by 0x19C1D1: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x195304: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x171F13: testing::Test::Run() (gtest-all.cc:3973)
==9137==    by 0x1728C2: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4149)
==9137==    by 0x172F7D: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4267)
==9137==    by 0x17E37E: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest-all.cc:6633)
==9137==    by 0x19D66B: bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x1963C6: bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x17CD7F: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gtest-all.cc:6242)
==9137==  Block was alloc'd at
==9137==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9137==    by 0x163DB1: Lista::agregarAtras(int const&) (Lista.hpp:94)
==9137==    by 0x165F85: lista_test_test_eliminar_elementos_Test::TestBody() (lista_tests.cpp:74)
==9137==    by 0x19C1D1: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x195304: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x171F13: testing::Test::Run() (gtest-all.cc:3973)
==9137==    by 0x1728C2: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4149)
==9137==    by 0x172F7D: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4267)
==9137==    by 0x17E37E: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest-all.cc:6633)
==9137==    by 0x19D66B: bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x1963C6: bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x17CD7F: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gtest-all.cc:6242)
==9137==
==9137== Invalid free() / delete / delete[] / realloc()
==9137==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9137==    by 0x163B86: Lista::~Lista() (Lista.hpp:21)
==9137==    by 0x1666DC: lista_test_test_eliminar_elementos_Test::TestBody() (lista_tests.cpp:93)
==9137==    by 0x19C1D1: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x195304: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x171F13: testing::Test::Run() (gtest-all.cc:3973)
==9137==    by 0x1728C2: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4149)
==9137==    by 0x172F7D: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4267)
==9137==    by 0x17E37E: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest-all.cc:6633)
==9137==    by 0x19D66B: bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x1963C6: bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x17CD7F: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gtest-all.cc:6242)
==9137==  Address 0x4dd9af0 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 24 free'd
==9137==    at 0x483CFBF: operator delete(void*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9137==    by 0x163FE2: Lista::eliminar(unsigned long) (Lista.hpp:148)
==9137==    by 0x1665F3: lista_test_test_eliminar_elementos_Test::TestBody() (lista_tests.cpp:91)
==9137==    by 0x19C1D1: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x195304: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x171F13: testing::Test::Run() (gtest-all.cc:3973)
==9137==    by 0x1728C2: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4149)
==9137==    by 0x172F7D: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4267)
==9137==    by 0x17E37E: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest-all.cc:6633)
==9137==    by 0x19D66B: bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x1963C6: bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x17CD7F: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gtest-all.cc:6242)
==9137==  Block was alloc'd at
==9137==    at 0x483BE63: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==9137==    by 0x163DB1: Lista::agregarAtras(int const&) (Lista.hpp:94)
==9137==    by 0x165F85: lista_test_test_eliminar_elementos_Test::TestBody() (lista_tests.cpp:74)
==9137==    by 0x19C1D1: void testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x195304: void testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::Test, void>(testing::Test*, void (testing::Test::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x171F13: testing::Test::Run() (gtest-all.cc:3973)
==9137==    by 0x1728C2: testing::TestInfo::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4149)
==9137==    by 0x172F7D: testing::TestCase::Run() (gtest-all.cc:4267)
==9137==    by 0x17E37E: testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::RunAllTests() (gtest-all.cc:6633)
==9137==    by 0x19D66B: bool testing::internal::HandleSehExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3899)
==9137==    by 0x1963C6: bool testing::internal::HandleExceptionsInMethodIfSupported<testing::internal::UnitTestImpl, bool>(testing::internal::UnitTestImpl*, bool (testing::internal::UnitTestImpl::*)(), char const*) (gtest-all.cc:3935)
==9137==    by 0x17CD7F: testing::UnitTest::Run() (gtest-all.cc:6242)
==9137==
```

Comment: Cual es la diferencia entre los dos casos? Es el mismo código. Qué más da si hay 1 elemento o 15 si lo vas a meter el primero?

Comment: ¿En qué te basas para afirmar que hay un problema en tu función? Deberías describir  un poco el problema para que sepamos qué es lo que tenemos que buscar. Por otro lado, es probable que el problema no se encuentre necesariamente en esa función

Comment: supuse por los test que tiene problemas esta función, la separe en esos tres casos para acortar la cantidad de problemas que tenia, podria detallar otras funciones o el problema mismo, no se la verdad que puede ser.